# What are these parallel connected lines meant for?

Tags: transmission-line, power-engineering

[image]

During my walk today, I noticed these small parallel connected lines. What purpose do they serve?

Comment: They may be a type of anti-resonance bar similar to the [Stockbridge damper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockbridge_damper).

Comment: DonFusili has already edited your question, but next time please refrain from 'text talk' language.

Comment: Dampers are calibrated weights. These appear to be crimped on jumpers.

Answer (score 1):

Not certain, but:

Cable joins in a long run of cable.
The strength join is not adequately electrically conductive and the ',jumpers' provide lower resistance joins.

Answer (score 0):

These are most probably points installed from where, in future, power cables can be attached to supply to nearby consumers.